# Similarity score between 2 words using Pre-trained BERT using Pytorch

Tags: natural-language-processing, bert, similarity

I'm trying to compare Glove, Fasttext, Bert on the basis of similarity between 2 words using Pre-trained Models. Glove and Fasttext had pre-trained models that could easily be used with gensim word2vec in python.

> **Does BERT have any such models?**
>
> **Is it possible to check the similarity between two words using BERT?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Does BERT have any such models?**

If you mean the **pretrained model**, then the answer is YES.
BERT has Cased and Uncased models and also models for other language (`BERT-Base, Multilingual Cased` and `BERT-Base, Multilingual Uncased`, trained in 104 languages). You can check those models [here](https://github.com/google-research/bert#pre-trained-models).

**2. Is it possible to check similarity between two words using BERT?**

Refer to [this Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZQvuAVwA3IjybezQOXnrXMGAnMyZRuPU#scrollTo=BokW7CAgMxCB), it is **not appopriate** with BERT Embeddings for **Word-Level similarity comparisons**.

However, doing **sentence embedding similarity comparisons** are still valid with BERT.

That's it, hope it helps you :)